# Como agregar datatable a una lista de ajax

Tags: mysql, laravel, ajax

Tengo el siguiente formulario que al ingresar dos fechas me lista por ajax el resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es un js.

```
$('#frm_range_date').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  url: $(this).attr('action'),
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  beforeSend: function(){
  $('#body_range_date').html('<br><p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></p><br>');
},  
success: function (data) {
console.log(data);      
  var val = 0;
  var estado = "";
  html3= '<span>'; 
  $.each(data, function(index, value){       
      val = val +1 ;
      html3 += "<tr>";        
      html3 += "<td class='text-center'>"+val+"</td>";
      html3 += "<td>"+value.ruc+"</td>";          
      html3 += "<td>"+value.businessName+"</td>";  
      html3 += "<td>"+value.name+"</td>";  
      html3 += "<td class='text-center'>"+value.total+"</td>";  
      html3 += "<td class='text-center'> S/. "+value.precio+" soles</td>";  
      html3 += "</tr>";  
      $('#body_range_date').html(html3);      
  });
}
})
```

});

lo que quisiera es saber si hay manera de agregar **datatable** a mi resultado en ajax. para poder tener el filtro y la paginacion automaticamente.

Comment: Ya probaste con `$('#body_range_date').DataTable();`?

Comment: Asi es, me sale el filtro pero no la paginacion, ademas cuando coloco algún texto en el filtro, no se filtra y se borra la lista.